# MVVM in KMM Compose UI

Tags: mvvm, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to implement an app with the mvvm architecture in KMM Compose UI.

Sadly I can't find a way doing it. All the tutorials I can find are for KMM but not for KMM Compose UI.

I'm trying to add the dependencies for using view models but it isn't possible:

```kotlin
commonMain.dependencies {
    implementation(compose.runtime)
    implementation(compose.foundation)
    implementation(compose.material)
    implementation(compose.ui)

    // These ones I'm trying to add
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.fragment.ktx)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
    implementation(compose.components.resources)
}
```

I'm getting following error while syncing:

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':composeApp:iosArm64CompilationDependenciesMetadata'.`

Is there a way for using mvvm in KMM Compose UI?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, AndroidX ViewModel library is not adapted yet for being used in the common target. You can still use AndroidX ViewModel in the Android target if you want.

```
kotlin {
    commonMain.dependencies {
        // Your common libraries here like Compose
        implementation(compose.runtime)
        implementation(compose.foundation)
        implementation(compose.material3)
        implementation(compose.ui)
        implementation(compose.components.resources)
    }

    androidMain.dependencies {
        // Your android libraries here
        implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
        implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
        implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
        implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
        implementation(libs.androidx.activity.ktx)
        implementation(libs.androidx.fragment.ktx)
    }
}
```

But if you need to share the logic in the common target, it exists many alternatives that use the same concept as ViewModel with Kotlin Multiplatform. Here are other libraries that do the same job in KMP:

- [KMM-ViewModel](https://github.com/rickclephas/KMM-ViewModel)
- [Summer](https://github.com/adevone/summer)
- [kmp-viewmodel](https://github.com/hoc081098/kmp-viewmodel)

Here libraries that manage navigation and state management:

- [Voyager](https://voyager.adriel.cafe/)
- [Decompose](https://arkivanov.github.io/Decompose/)

I recommend you to take a look at [Awesome Kotlin Multiplatform](https://Awesome%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform) which reference a lot of KMP libraries.